# asp.net, sql server new table connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I created new table in an existing SQL Server database, but can't find the connection string to connect my script to the database. I am a java developer and am using asp.net for the very first time. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the type of database you are connecting to, but this site has examples for many types of databases. http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can use Server Explorer to connect to the database

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx if you're using a different type of connection string (such as for the Entity Framework), you'll need to [edit] and provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't nearly enough information in your question to give a definitive answer, but the link below should get you started on the various types of connection strings and how to configure them:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

A pretty common format is:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

The values you need to enter should be pretty clear based on the example values entered.